# Replace "\" with "/" in r

Tags: r, filepath, read.table

I'm trying to replace "\" with "/" or "\\" in R.

```
fp = "C:\users\jordan\Documents\Computer Science\R\miscData.txt"
replace(fp, "\", "\\")


Output:
> fp = "C:\users\jordan\Documents\Computer Science\R\miscData.txt"
Error: '\u' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\u"
```

Obviously, "\" is an escape character and can't be used this way. Is there a way to avoid the use of "\" as an escape character in R?

Comment: Can't you just escape it again? I.e., use '\\\\' instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scan function. In your example:

```
X = scan(what="character",allowEscapes=F, nmax = 1)
"C:\users\jordan\Documents\Computer Science\R\miscData.txt"
```

The result:

```
X
[1] "C:\\users\\jordan\\Documents\\Computer Science\\R\\miscData.txt"
```