# Replace '\' by '/' in without using scan() or clipboard

Tags: r

I want to replace '\' by '/' regardless of how many times it is present in the input string.

I have read these : [Replace "\" with "/" in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48481245/replace-with-in-r)

[Efficiently convert backslash to forward slash in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605563/efficiently-convert-backslash-to-forward-slash-in-r)

But both of them gives solution where the directory_path is read through clipboard paste or through scan().

I want to give directory path as a variable.

Example Code :

```
directory_path = 'D:\demo\app'

gsub( '\', '/', directory_path )
```

But it is giving error.

```
> directory_path = 'D:\demo\app'
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'D:\d"
```

Comment: Escape like so: `test<-c("D:\\demo\\app")`.

Comment: I wonder how many questions about R's need to doubly escape the `"\"` there are. I suspect they number in the hundreds. Well, maybe not. Here's the result of a search, but most of the answers are not on point: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+replace+%27%5C%27

Comment: the path will be input by user say and he cannot be asked to give input with double slash. How to tackle that part ? I initiated this question just for this. Haven't found answer to this form in other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Escape them like:

```
test <- c("D:\\demo\\app")
```

Then:

```
gsub("\\\\", "/", test)
```

Comment: the directory path will be given input by a user say, who does not know about escape characters. He will give 'D:\demo\app' and cannot be asked to give otherwise. How to tackle it ?